# Reset MFA for user in B2C tenant

Tags: entra-id

I have an account that is linked with multiple Azure tenants - one normal one, and a few B2C tenants. All of which have MFA registered. I know how to update my main tenant MFA - but I can't see any way to do the same with the other tenants. They're the same login (email/password) - but have different MFA registrations. I'm changing authenticator app - so would like to re-do those MFA registrations.

If I go to my user in B2C, MFA stuff is greyed out...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the screenshot in my initial post where those buttons are greyed out - are always greyed out if you're looking at your own user. I had to get someone else on the team to click those buttons against my user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to azure ad not azure b2c and then go to Users > the link for per user mfa will be available here.

Comment: Thanks, but the user won't be in Azure AD - that's my main account's MFA - not the MFA against the B2C tenant. I solved it in the end - I'll post the solution as a separate answer.

Comment: I was doing this yesterday. When you’re signed into the b2c tenant search azure ad in the azure search and it will open azad settings relative to the b2c.

Comment: Did this let you update your own MFA though? I tried that, and nothing would let me update my own MFA - even if I'm global admin. I see the same thing happening just with normal AAD too.

Comment: I can reset other people's MFA though.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable/re-enable MFA per user
You can also enable MFA in a User Flow

Comment: User flow won't work, because this isn't a user that can log into my app - it's my own user for managing B2C. Also, I can't find a way to disable/re-enable it in the UI - the MFA options are greyed out (I've updated post with a screenshot).

Comment: If you want to configure MFA for non-admin users only use Authentication Administrator role and if you want to configure MFA for all users including admin users, use Privileged Authentication Administrator role        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/40051/admin-permission-for-mfa

Comment: I was global admin anyway. Just noticed that it looks like the "reset mfa" buttons are only greyed out if it's my own account. Which is weird. So I'll have to get someone else on the team tomorrow to reset mine.